# Lynx Web Browser Crashing

Tags: cmd, lynx

I am using the lynx web browerser (v2.8) from the command line with the following command:

```
lynx -crawl -dump  "http://www.urlhere.com" >1
```

When I paste the code into CMD one at a time it works fine.

Normally, when I am running command line scripts (i.e. python), I am able to copy and paste multiple lines in so the script runs in batch mode (each line runs one at a time).  In the past I have been able to do this with 100's of lines at a time.

example:
    lynx -crawl -dump  "http://www.urlhere.com/0/" >0
    lynx -crawl -dump  "http://www.urlhere.com/1/" >1

When I try to do this with Lynx, the program crashes as soon as I paste the multiple lines in.

Is there a way to get this to work, or at least at a delay to the script command to delay the next line from loading?  I haven't had to do this delay with Python.  I am hoping there is a way to get this to run in batch mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
start "" /b lynx -crawl -dump  "http://www.urlhere.com" >1
```

BTW: in this setting is `1` the name of a file. If you need no output send it to `NUL`.

Comment: That opens a new window and runs through the script, but it generates a 0 kb (blank) file.  Using the original formula above the file is actually 5 kb.  Also, as I will be using this on hundreds of items, ideally, I would like it to stay within the single command line window.  But it that's not possible I'm OK with the new windows opening.

Comment: Wow!  That works great.  Thanks for your assistance.  This solves a big problem for me~  Thank you